# If operating cash flow yield of a company is negative along with revenue growth for current year , does that mean the company is in deep trouble?

Tags: stocks, stock-analysis, cash-flow

I subscribed to one technical analytics service for the stock market. Here is one company whose fundamental indicators, I was looking at.

Below is the fundamental analysis comparison of peer companies and the current company :
[Fundamental indicators of Rajesh Exports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exNYv.png)

[Operating cash flow of Rajesh Exports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XnB7.png)

I can see that under the earnings quality section,the company has reported negative growth in Operating Cash Flow Yield and Accruals.

Still, the analytics company has maintained a positive outlook about earning quality.

My question is :

- as per my understanding, negative operating cash flow yield means bad for a company? Am I correct?

Comment: depends how negative and what the plan is to correct that.

Comment: @RobertLongson : can you please explain a bit ?

Comment: Company is worth $1billion, cashflow is negative by $1 for one year and next year resumes growing. Would that company be in deep trouble?

Comment: Is it a **one-year** drop in cash flow and revenue, or **multi-year**?

Comment: @RonJohn : it is one-year drop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Negative *growth* is not a bad thing, especially for only one year. It just means that their cash flow was lower this year than last year.  Now if cash flow *itself* goes negative, that could be a bad sign, but again not necessarily time to panic.

Both are negative *indicators* (meaning that it's better to have positive growth than negative), but neither necessarily means a company is "in trouble".

Answer (score 0):

> reported negative growth in Operating Cash Flow Yield and Accruals.
>
> it is one-year drop

A one year drop is just that:  **one year**.

What's the long-term trend?  Is there a history of up and down years, but mostly up?  It might be in a cyclical market where this is expected.